# concatenate strings in javascript embedded in xsl

Tags: xslt, string-concatenation

I have this script embedded in my xsl file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
     window.onload = function(){
         var success = new PDFObject({url:"http://19.46.1.34:8081/xmlui{mets:FLocat/@xlink:href}"}).embed("pdf");
     }
 </script>
```

I dont know how to concantenate the string parameter of the function PDFObject. It should be like this.

```
url: "http://19.46.1.34:8081/xmlui" +valueof{mets:FLocat/@xlink:href}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to use `<xsl:text>` and `<xsl:value-of>`:

```xml
<scriptx type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:text>
        window.onload = function(){
           var success = new PDFObject({url:"http://19.46.1.34:8081/xmlui</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="mets:FLocat/@xlink:href"/>
  <xsl:text>"}).embed("pdf");
        }
   </xsl:text>
</scriptx>
```

(I substituted `<script>` for `<scriptx>` so that the content will be highlighted as XML instead of JavaScript)